# How to share object(s) among methods of a TestClass without mentioning them in each method (using pytest)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

Suppose I have a class something like this:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tab1 = data.A
        self.tab2 = data.B

    # Other methods which try to change the state of object
    def add1(self, num):
        self.tab1 += num

    def mul2(self, num):
        self.tab2 *= num
```

Using pytest, I'm trying to test the state of object of `Class` (say `obj`) when several operations are done. For each operation I want a different test function but all of them should manipulate the same object. Since pytest doesn't allow using `__init__` for test classes, only options I have is to create `obj` as class variable or return it from a class-scoped fixture as mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371832/how-to-share-the-same-instance-for-all-methods-of-a-pytest-test-class). But I can't make `obj` class variable because it needs `class_data` fixture for instantiating, so I return it from a class-scoped fixture, like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def class_data():
    return pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})

class TestClass:
    @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def obj(self, class_data):
        return Class(class_data)

    def test_state1(self, obj):
        obj.add1(5)
        print(obj.tab1, obj.tab2)
        assert obj.tab1.equals(pd.Series([1, 2, 3])+5)

    def test_state2(self, obj):
        obj.mul2(2)
        print(obj.tab1, obj.tab2)
        assert obj.tab2.equals(pd.Series([4, 5, 6])*2)
```

So far so good, but what if I have so many methods - I don't want to pass it individually to each method. Thus following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135020/8252556), I tried to create a `autouse` fixture (with class scope), like this:

```
class TestClass:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup_the_class(self, class_data):
        self.obj = Class(class_data)

    def test_state1(self):
        self.obj.add1(5)
        print(self.obj.tab1, self.obj.tab2)
        assert self.obj.tab1.equals(pd.Series([1, 2, 3])+5)

    def test_state2(self):
        self.obj.mul2(2)
        print(self.obj.tab1, self.obj.tab2)
        assert self.obj.tab2.equals(pd.Series([4, 5, 6])*2)
```

But it gives `AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'obj'`.

I don't understand why this happens? Even [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids) mentions:

> The class-level transact fixture is marked with `autouse=True` which implies that all test methods in the class will use this fixture without a need to state it in the test function signature or with a class-level `usefixtures` decorator.

Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong here and how `autouse` fixtures actually work? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Besides, this `autouse` fixture approach also seems useful to me because it allows me (in theory) to define several other objects which use a fixture for their creation (like `obj` does) as members of TestClass (as `self.<some_variable>`) so that I will not need to define each of them in the separate class-scoped fixture that returns them. This theory is coming from my observation (assumption perhaps) that fixtures with `autouse` (or `usefixtures`) do not return/yield anything they just change the state of an entity that will be used by test methods, indirectly i.e. without passing as an argument. So my second question is whether I'm thinking in the right direction or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class scoped fixture, the `self` parameter is not the same instance as the instance used in tests. The instance used in the fixture is created *before* all test instances, the fixture code until the `yield` is called, then for each test a new test instance is created, executed and deletd, and after that the code after the `yield` (e.g. the teardown code, if there is any) is called, and the fixture instance is deleted.

So, while you can't use `self` to store your object, you can store it in the class instead using `self.__class__`:

```py
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup_the_class(self, class_data):
        self.__class__.obj = Class(class_data)
```

The data can be accessed from the tests as before as `self.obj`, because the lookup will find it in the class if it does not exist in the instance.

That being said, your test code does not look like you want to have a class scoped fixture. You change the value of the fixture in each test, and it stays changed that way, so te test outcome depends on the sequence the tests are executed. This is true for both versions of the test. In case this true in your real test, you probably want to use a function scoped fixture instead, that recreates the object for each test (and wehre you can save it in an instance variable).